# Is there a tool to check mysql/mariadb database is all OK?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Today, Mariadb went down on one of my servers. The specific issue was something to do with ibdata1 file being locked. I found a website that showed how to fix it, and so all was OK. So I thought.

30 minutes later it went down again, same issue, same fix.

Its now running OK but I am worried it will happen again. I dont know why this would just happen when its been running fine for so long. Its a Linode server that runs Virtualmin for LAMP stack website hosting. Quite straightforward.

So I wondered if there is some sort of tool that can check over the DB and files to check there is nothing corrupt or untoward. Much like you do for operating systems, checking the disk is OK, defragging windows etc. Anything that gives the DB a once over to check all is OK.

Comment: please post the mysql error log file. Common this log file is in data dir, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145627/error-log-location

Answer (score 2):

Verifying that a MariaDB or MySQL instance is "OK" is a complicated task, not least because there are different levels of "OK", and one man's "OK" is another man's "not OK". There are various tools you can use, though. To name a few in no particular order:

- Percona Toolkit's [pt-variable-advisor](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-variable-advisor.html)
- [`SHOW ENGINE ...`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-engine/) e.g. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`,
- Activate and check the [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/slow-query-log-overview/)
- [PMM - Percona Monitoring & Management](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html)
- [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog)
- mysql-tuner, see e.g. article [here](https://linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-optimize-mysql-performance-using-mysqltuner/).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has some basic tools described in the chapter [13.7.3 Maintenance statements *(version 8)*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-maintenance-statements.html):

```
13.7.3.1 ANALYZE TABLE Syntax
13.7.3.2 CHECK TABLE Syntax
13.7.3.3 CHECKSUM TABLE Syntax
13.7.3.4 OPTIMIZE TABLE Syntax
13.7.3.5 REPAIR TABLE Syntax
```

Comment: So your answer is a no then, because these are table specifics not DB as a whole. Its not practical to check all tables individually if you dont know which ones may have issues.

Comment: I've used `HeidiSQL` client that allows to check all the tables belonging to some DB recursively. Sure `MysqlBench` can do the same. I'm not sure about `phpMyAdmin` but you always can write a script like `for dbtab IN $(show tables) ; do check table $dbtab; done;`

Comment: Also `DB` or `scheme` in terms of `MySQL` is just a scope for names and have no additional internals to maintain ACIDity or any kind of consistency. Within same db/scheme you can refer other entities (tables/views/procedures/funtions etc) directly without any db.prefix. Also it is used for the storage/filesystem path. But "database" isn't a thing that can be checked/repaired as single entity.